# Alpha Beta Pruning with Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am working through the Minimax algorithm with Alpha-Beta Pruning example found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-4-alpha-beta-pruning/). In the example, they use an array to implement the search tree. I followed the example, but also tried implementing it with a binary search tree as well. Here are the values I'm using in the tree: 3, 5, 6, 9, 1, 2, 0, -1.

The optimal value at the end should be 5. With the BST implementation, I keep getting 2.

I think this is the problem, but I don't know how to get around it:
I wrote the code to return out of recursion if it sees a leaf node to stop from getting null pointer exceptions when trying to check the next value. But instead, I think it's stopping the search too early (based off of what I see when stepping through the code with the debugger). If I remove the check though, the code fails on a null pointer.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
public class AlphaBetaMiniMax {

    private static BinarySearchTree myTree = new BinarySearchTree();
    static int MAX = 1000;
    static int MIN = -1000;
    static int opt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Start constructing the game
        AlphaBetaMiniMax demo = new AlphaBetaMiniMax();

        //3, 5, 6, 9, 1, 2, 0, -1
        demo.myTree.insert(3);
        demo.myTree.insert(5);
        demo.myTree.insert(6);
        demo.myTree.insert(9);
        demo.myTree.insert(1);
        demo.myTree.insert(2);
        demo.myTree.insert(0);
        demo.myTree.insert(-1);

        //print the tree
        System.out.println("Game Tree: ");
        demo.myTree.printTree(demo.myTree.root);

        //Print the results of the game
        System.out.println("\nGame Results:");

        //run the  minimax algorithm with the following inputs
        int optimalVal = demo.minimax(0, myTree.root, true, MAX, MIN);
        System.out.println("Optimal Value: " + optimalVal);

    }

    /**
     * @param alpha = 1000
     * @param beta = -1000
     * @param nodeIndex - the current node
     * @param depth - the depth to search
     * @param maximizingPlayer - the current player making a move
     * @return - the best move for the current player
     */
    public int minimax(int depth, MiniMaxNode nodeIndex, boolean maximizingPlayer, double alpha, double beta) {

        //Base Case #1: Reached the bottom of the tree
        if (depth == 2) {
            return nodeIndex.getValue();
        }

        //Base Case #2: if reached a leaf node, return the value of the current node
        if (nodeIndex.getLeft() == null && maximizingPlayer == false) {
            return nodeIndex.getValue();
        } else if (nodeIndex.getRight() == null && maximizingPlayer == true) {
            return nodeIndex.getValue();
        }

        //Mini-Max Algorithm
        if (maximizingPlayer) {
            int best = MIN;

            //Recur for left and right children
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                int val = minimax(depth + 1, nodeIndex.getLeft(), false, alpha, beta);
                best = Math.max(best, val);
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, best);

                //Alpha Beta Pruning
                if (beta <= alpha) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return best;
        } else {
            int best = MAX;

            //Recur for left and right children
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                int val = minimax(depth + 1, nodeIndex.getRight(), true, alpha, beta);
                best = Math.min(best, val);
                beta = Math.min(beta, best);

                //Alpha Beta Pruning
                if (beta <= alpha) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return best;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Game Tree: 
-1 ~ 0 ~ 1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 5 ~ 6 ~ 9 ~ 
Game Results:
Optimal Value: 2
```

Comment: could you post a complete code containing the inputs?

Comment: @kelalaka I edited my post to include the input and output. I think I may have found part of the problem, but I am still getting a value of 2. I think another problem is that I think for each run, I'm not checking both sides of the tree. I'm either checking the left or right - not all children. I'm still trying to figure out how to work through it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your iterations are depending on a loop control of 2, and not a node == null finding for nodeIndex.getRight()(for max)  getLeft(for min.)

Remember a tree has 
1 head(first level)

2nd level = 2

3rd level = 4

4th 8
and so on.  So your algorithm for looping will not even go down 3 levels.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

     int val = minimax(depth + 1, nodeIndex.getLeft(), false, alpha, beta);
                best = Math.max(best, val);
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, best);

                //Alpha Beta Pruning
                if (beta <= alpha) {
                    break;
                }
```

Change your loops to control iteration correctly and you should find the highest value easily.

Comment: That makes sense. So, instead of the for loop, I tried this: I run miniMax() on the left node > calculate best > calculate alpha > calculate beta <= alpha > then do miniMax() on the right node. My logic is to do something similar to a tree traversal for printing (recursively call print(node.left) > print the node value > recursively call print(node.right)). I'm still getting 2 though. Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: That is correct you need a traversal that will find the min(far left node) of a BST, and the max(far right node) using an iteration that will completely traverse the tree left side and right side to find the values.  Yes you are on the right track, don't use for loops to iterate a tree.  that is what the nodeIndex.left and nodeIndex.right or the getleft and getright does.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree    Please use link for a more indepth explanation of the BST tree and functionality of it

Comment: If I helped to solve your issue please put the answered check on it.

Comment: I got it! Thanks for your help.